# Improve performance for solving linear systems in parallel with multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, sparse-matrix

when solving a coupled system of parabolic PDEs, I need to solve linear systems in each time step. By using an IMEX method I can solve these linear systems in parallel and only have to update the right-hand sides in each time step.

My attempt was to use a pool of workers from `multiprocessing`, sparse matrices and the sparse solver from `scipy.sparse`. Unfortunately, the solving the equations in parallel isn't really that much faster.

The matrices `Mat1`, `Mat2`, `Mat3` and `Mat4` are for all time steps the same, the vectors `b1`, `b2`, `b3` and `b4` have to be updated in every time step and depend on each other, i.e. I have something like `b1 = b1+b2+b3**2`.
I was thinking of using a `multiprocessing.Array`, but as far as I understand it's purpose is to enable the processes to change the given data, which I don't really need.

Is there some way to use increase the performance of `multiprocessing`?

I just started to work with `multiprocessing` and therefore I'm not familiar yet with the all the possibilities.
Thank you for your help in advance :-)

```
sparse_Mat1 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(Mat1)
sparse_Mat2 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(Mat2)
sparse_Mat3 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(Mat3)
sparse_Mat4 = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(Mat4)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
# time steps
while t <= T+1/2*dt:

  # stuff to update b1, b2, b3 and b4
  ...

  res1 = pool.apply_async(scipy.sparse.linalg, [sparse_Mat1, b1])
  res2 = pool.apply_async(scipy.sparse.linalg, [sparse_Mat2, b2])
  res3 = pool.apply_async(scipy.sparse.linalg, [sparse_Mat3, b3])
  res4 = pool.apply_async(scipy.sparse.linalg, [sparse_Mat4, b4])

  sol1 =  = res1.get()
  sol2 =  = res2.get()
  sol3 =  = res3.get()
  sol4 =  = res4.get()
pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

1) consider [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) -- this evaluates function in parallel. Think of it as an extention of scipy.

2) for multiprocessing: in general it's best to have a `Pool` of workers.  For each step, send data to a worker and retrieve it using `map()` (or `imap_unordered`).  **Example follows**

There's an overhead to sending/receiving data to other processes, so each proc should do as much work as possible with as little I/O as possible.  In your example, `b1 = b1+b2+b3**2`, so this is rather tricky.

### source

```
import multiprocessing

def calc(num):
    return num*2

if __name__=='__main__':  # required for Windows
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()   # one Process per CPU
    for output in pool.map(calc, [1,2,3]):
        print 'output:',output
```

### output

```
output: 2
output: 4
output: 6
```